# javascript: Using lodash/fp flow to return objects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I am converting a _.chain group of functions to use _fp.flow, but am having some difficulty dealing with the way flow curries complex objects. I am trying to

1. Reduce an array of objects with some grouped function (e.g. `countBy`/`sumBy`) into a object/dictionary (e.g. `{ group1:10, group2:15... }` )
2. Map it into an array of key/value pairs (e.g. `[{column: 'group1', value: '10'}, ...]`)
3. Sort by some variable into `asc/desc` order

but right now the resulting object ends up being flattened into a long array. A sample of the code is below. The `reducer` function in the code below is working correctly and grouping the values as I intended, but then I think the currying between the `each` step and `orderBy` is flattening the object somehow (the desired object is formed correctly after `_.each` in the `console.log`.

I've put a sample of the code in the attached JSFiddle.

```
const inData = [{
  target: 123,
  groupby: 'a'
},...
}];

const colData = _.flow(
  _.reduce(reducer, {}),
  _.toPairs,
  _.each(([value, column]) => {
    console.log(value); 
    console.log(column);
    const outObj = {
        value: value,
      column: column
    }
    console.log(outObj)
    return (outObj);
  }),
  _.orderBy(['value'], [sortDir]),
  // Have tried result with or without fromPairs 
    _.fromPairs 
)(inData);
```

PS: I am using ES6 syntax and React in my main project, if that makes a difference.

https://jsfiddle.net/moc0L5ac/

Comment: You should include sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `map` instead of `each` and also fix the order of `[value, column]` to `[column, value]`

```
const colData = _.flow(
  _.reduce(reducer, {}),
  _.toPairs,
  _.map(([column, value]) => {
      const outObj = {
        value: value,
        column: column
      }
      return outObj;
    }),
  _.orderBy(['value'], [sortDir])
)(inData);
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best my understanding, this is what you're looking to accomplish

```
const inData =
  [ { target: 123, groupby: 'a' },
    { target: -123, groupby: 'b' },
    { target: 123, groupby: 'a' },
    { target: -123, groupby: 'b' } ]

const colData = _.flow(
  _.reduce((map, {target:v, groupby:k}) =>
    Object.assign(map, { [k]: map[k] === undefined ? v : map[k] + v }), {}),
  _.toPairs,
  _.map(([column, value]) => ({ column, value }))
)

console.log(colData(inData));
// => [ { column: 'a', value: 246 },
//      { column: 'b', value: -246 } ]
```